# $.getJSON callback does work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experimenting with jQuery and I try to use the `$.getJSON` function

I red that "A reference to a function declaration could equally be provided as the callback". So instead of an anonymous function, I use a reference to a function declaration like this

```
$('#letter-b').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON('b.js', outside(data));
});

function outside (data){alert(data);}
```

I get no alert. Instead I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

What am I missing? Is it my syntax?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You must give the reference to your function. Like this :

```
$('#letter-b').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON('b.js', outside);
});
```

If you write `outside(data)`, you just execute your function.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how the `data` is transfered from the callback to the function, if dont include it in the callback ?

Comment: @slevin: You cannot include it because *you* don't have the `data` when the element is clicked. The `getJSON` function, when *it* has the data, *will* call the callback function and pass the response.

Comment: jQuery give the data to your function when it have it. So you don't have to wonder how you get it.

Comment: @slevin under the hood the `getJSON` function upon receiving response does something like `callback.call( this, response )` which calls the function passed as callback and supplies the context and argument.